# No Wi-Fi adapter found / My intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 is UNCLAIMED in lshw -c network

Tags: iwlwifi

I have just turned on my laptop and my wifi is not available! I cannot see my wifi settings and turn it On/Off [Check this Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xKKi.png) and [This Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCit8.png). I have installed my ubuntu alongside windows 10.
First time that i used ubuntu my wifi did worked pretty well. Im using ***Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS*** and my kernel version is ***Linux 5.8.0-48-generic***, which is updated to the latest version.
I did searched many times but can't find any solution for this problem.

I have collected some informations about my Wi-Fi by the following [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1192137) and paste the output here:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Apr 2021 12:44 +0430 +0430

Booted last: 13 Apr 2021 00:00 +0430 +0430

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.8.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1869 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5666 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:185d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS GT300 GAMING MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

EFI variables are not supported on this system

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               352256  0
wl                   6455296  0
cfg80211              778240  2 wl,iwlwifi
asus_nb_wmi            32768  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
asus_wmi               36864  2 asus_nb_wmi,hid_asus
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  2 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  49152  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.107/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 256142sec preferred_lft 256142sec
    inet6 fe80::efe1:cc81:c33a:50cb/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.107 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         932       1  0 11:48 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.8.0-48-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       84a732b3-4e01-3cca-938e-104fbbdfa6c9
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.107/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 259200
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name = 
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1618557803
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        host_name = dhcppc7
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.107
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::efe1:cc81:c33a:50cb/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   84a732b3-4e01-3cca-938e-104fbbdfa6c9 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/D-LINK.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=D-LINK | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=D-LINK
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Bobby.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Bobby | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Bobby
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Babak’s iPhone.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Babak’s iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=66;97;98;97;107;226;128;153;115;32;105;80;104;111;110;101;
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tehran (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.8.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       5.8.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.8.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   36.243679] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[  149.936075] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[  149.936097] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[  236.826609] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[  320.308708] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110
[  342.603789] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[ 1130.713297] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110

########## wireless info END ############
```

Also this is my "sudo lshw -c network":

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 2c:fd:a1:af:ed:89
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df304000-df304fff memory:df300000-df303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df100000-df101fff
```

i'll be grateful if anybody could help me.

Comment: You may want to go back to the 5.4 version kernel.

Comment: I have same due to updates. I conclude the Nvidia packages are related because some versions of kernel 5.8.0.xx won't launch X11. Suspect planning for Wayland is related. However, after clearing out Nvidia, I solved display problem but now wifi and TouchPad do not work. Wired ethereal OK. Intel Wifi 6 AX200 on Dell Precision 7200

Comment: Same problem but I'm not dual booting, just a pure Ubuntu 22.10 install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved** my problem just by turning off my laptop by holding power button!
because i have **Ubuntu** alongside **Windows 10**, I think both of them will affects each other and change some setting before Shutdown/Restart; Like some problems of **headphone** or this **WiFi** problem.

I hope this will help other friends.

Comment: I had the same problem without dual booting. I am running Ubuntu only. But, this solution helped. Here was my question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367543/no-wi-fi-device-found-by-networkmanager

Answer (score 5):

To properly solve this issue you have to disable Windows fast startup:

[image: Windows Control Panel]

And when leaving Windows always do a shutdown because as you can see in the config "restart isn't affected".

As stated in the [iwlwifi documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled):

> **About dual-boot with Windows and "fast-boot" enabled**
>
> If you have a dual-boot machine with a recent version of Windows and
> start seeing problems during initialization of the WiFi device when
> booting Linux, the problem could be due to the “fast startup” feature
> on Windows.
>
> With this feature enabled, Windows don't really shut down the entire
> system, but leaves things partially running so you can start the
> machine faster again. Try to disable this option, on Windows 10 it
> should be in “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System
> Settings”. Select “Chooose what the power buttons do” to access the
> System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast
> Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”. This will cause Windows to
> fully shutdown and may solve the issue.

Comment: Nothing can be left "partially running" when the the CPU and RAM have no power.

Comment: This is the iwlwifi documentation, not mine. Don't shoot the messenger. Besides that, changing this config solves the problem anyway.

Comment: Upvoting, this actually worked! I can't believe it did but it did.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working for me

Comment: **Windows fast startup** was the problem! Solved right away! Anything else failed miserably! Just **disable Windows Fast startup**, after you find where they've hidden it! On Kubuntu 22.04 Dell XPS 13 9370

Comment: Note that **if Windows is in Hibernate** state in a dual boot config, you get the same behaviour (**Wifi card is not recognised on Linux**). 

How is this is even possible and who's to blame (Microsoft or Intel drivers) is a good question...!

Answer (score 5):

Just registered to add up to this, so I can't upvote and/or comment, but the "Turn off fast startup" in Windows does the trick and needs to be set as the best answer, as the "power off by holding the power button" is really bad for the file system

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me too, the turn off by pressing holdig the power button and in the grub menu choosed ubuntu. I could see that the description of the network changed from "Network Controler" to "Wireless Interface". Very weird solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the Windows and "fast-boot" is the key!
When dual booting, windows 10 keeps the network card connected for faster boot up, which blocks use with ubuntu.
Described in the following link - https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in that case it was a partially successful upgrade process. Use the 'lsmod' command to see if the driver is actually loaded. If it is not, you may need to connect to the internet by other means and download the driver or use the installation media to add the driver back in.  Alternatively, maybe you could boot in to an older kernel via the grub menu?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please explain 'driver's? Kernel module?

Comment: This is the actual driver that is loaded in to the kernel. The easiest is probably if you can use a usb ethernet cable and plug in somewhere THEN use the "Additional Drivers" tool in Ubuntu to add what you need. It is an automatic process...

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my issue! I have a Geekom Mini IT11 PC, with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Windows 11 on dual boot. Whenever I log into Windows and then log into Ubuntu, I run into the same issue as described above.

For the scenarios where Ubuntu is unable to connect to Wi-Fi, in journalctl, below logs are generated.

```
$> journalclt|grep iwlwifi
......
......
......
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CSR_RESET = 0x10
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f1d0430
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f1d0030
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x040066c2
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0xa00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0xf00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0xf00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0xf00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0xa00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0xf00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0xe00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0xf00c7c75
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x51cec019
Feb 02 19:16:12 <my PC> kernel: iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
```

After disabling the setting in Windows discussed in the above solution, I power it down and then log in Ubuntu. Wifi connects fine now, and I get the below log in journalctl:

```
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x20000302 wfpm id 0x80000000
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev a0f0/0074, rev=0x351, rfid=0x10a100
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 77.2df8986f.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Feb 02 19:30:37 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
Feb 02 19:30:38 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B5, rfid=0x10a100
Feb 02 19:30:38 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: d4:d8:53:ee:e4:59
Feb 02 19:30:38 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
Feb 02 19:30:38 anupamPC NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1706923838.4503] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Feb 02 19:30:38 anupamPC kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met a similar issue:

- I couldn't see a list of WiFi to choose from (but I actually can use it, since I configured it during installation)
- I couldn't use Bluetooth (the toggle on the UI won't work)

The first problem was solved by [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411066/no-wifi-network-show-on-select-wifi-network-on-ubuntu-22-04), and the second was by running
`systemctl restart bluetooth.service`