# No Wi-Fi device found by NetworkManager

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

**System:** Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus Vivobook 15 (X415 / M415) [no other OS]

**Problem:** No Wi-Fi device found by NetworkManager:

```
root@bhagirathi:~# nmcli device wifi list
root@bhagirathi:~# nmcli device wifi rescan
Error: No Wi-Fi device found.
```

although driver is loaded correctly (see `lspci` below ) and device is not blocked (see `rfkill` below). `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` does not show any wireless adapter. The device is recognized by the kernel (see `lshw -C network` below).

[Edit: **Solved**. The problem was solved just by turning off the laptop by holding power button. [See original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348844/58161)]

**Network information**

- `lspci`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:0110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

- `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. AX88179
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0408:3046 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- `rfkill list`

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

- Secureboot disabled
- `lsmod`

```
iwlmvm                413696  0
mac80211             1024000  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
asus_wmi               36864  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon
video                  53248  1 asus_wmi
```

- `ifconfig`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.107/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 4102sec preferred_lft 4102sec
    inet6 fe80::83c9:fe89:50f0:fc82/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.
```

- NetworkManager State

```
root@bhagirathi:~# cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

- NetworkManager config

```
[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

- Netplan configuration

```
[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

- `dmesg | grep "iwlwifi"`

```
[   11.050516] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.131973] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   12.131983] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   12.132961] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.905140] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
```

- `lshw -C network`

```
root@bhagirathi:~# lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:fcf00000-fcf01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       serial: <MAC address>
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic duplex=full ip=192.168.0.107 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Comment: I suggest you to follow this guide. [https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en)

Comment: I followed this guide, and updated my question with the output from `lshw -C network`. As mentioned in the question, the device is recognized by the kernel and the driver. The correct driver is also being used. However, NetworkManager / nmcli does not recognize the wi-fi adapter.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: No, I have erased Windows, and running Ubuntu only.

Comment: Note that there is no `logical name` for the wireless network controller in `lshw -C network`.

Comment: The problem was solved just by turning off the laptop by holding power button. Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331104/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-my-intel-wireless-8265-8275-is-unclaimed-in-lshw-c-n