# No wifi Network show on select Wifi network on UBUNTU 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

after i upgraded to 22.04 my wifi is showing no networks I have reseted my network settings many times but no result I have even downgraded the kernel from 5.15 to old 5.13 still no result

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to tell `netplan` to use `NetworkManager`. You will have to add a line to the configuration file of `netplan`. So edit the `/etc/netplan/ 00-...-wifi.yaml` file with `sudo` privileges.

Find the flowing lines:

```
network:
  version: 2
```

and add the line:

```
renderer: NetworkManager
```

so it will now be like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Now, to activate the new line, you can type in the terminal either:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

which will apply the new line, or:

```
sudo netplan try
```

which will only try to apply for a few minutes, and reverts back automatically, if you don't approve it.

The Wi-Fi should start showing up, immediately.