# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found/Network Controller Unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, intel

I just recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9365 and I am having trouble getting my Intel Wi-Fi adapter to work properly. I have tried downloading the appropriate driver for my Network Controller (I have the Intel Wireless 8265/8275). I have tried numerous solutions I found online and nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Wi-Fi adapter found / My intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 is UNCLAIMED in lshw -c network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331104/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-my-intel-wireless-8265-8275-is-unclaimed-in-lshw-c-n)

Comment: Post results from terminal for `sudo dmesg | grep iwl; dpkg -l |grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`